# Easiest way to restore symbolic links turned into text files?

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, ln

I had folders with many symbolic links in them. Unfortunately after copying that around different filesystems, they've turned into plain text files with the link target as the contents. That is:

**Before**

```
$ ll link
... link -> /path/to/target
```

**After**

```
$ cat link
/path/to/target
```

What's the easiest way to restore this link? Perhaps a one-liner or a shell script.

Suppose I had hundreds of links like this, is there a way to restore them all, without manually running the fix on each one?

Comment: Get comfy with `debugfs`. Try to not cause *too* much damage...

Comment: `debugfs` is absolutely not the right tool to use here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which filesystems did you copy between, and what tools did you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this command:

```
ls *txt | xargs -I R1 sh -c "cat R1 | xargs -I R2 ln -sf R2 R1"
```

Replace `ls *txt` with something that will output the list of text files that should be symbolic links. For example, `find . -name "*txt"` would list all *txt files in or under the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ls * | while read f; do
  ln -sf "$(cat $f)" "$f" 
done
```

as in wingedsubmariner's answer, `ls *` should be replaced with something that will list exactly the files you wanted.

I find the

```
ls * | while read f; do
  # command executed for each file
done
```

construct very useful.  As I know, this is the right way to handle all file names, e.g. if a file name has spaces then "$f" will still work (unlike with `for f in $(ls *); do...done`).

FYI: $(cmd) is the same as `cmd` but it can be nested unlike ``.